# Click function not firing after a different function has fired

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery site that creates a string of thumbnails and then displays a larger version of a thumbnail and cycles to the next every 4 seconds. I wrote a click function so that the user can select a specific image by clicking on the thumbnail. The large "display" image would immediately transition to the image the user clicked, and the timer would be reset. I had some trouble when I tried to implement a function that paused the slideshow while the user hovered over the "display" image and then reset the timer on mouseLeave. I got it to work finally, but now my click function to select a specific image is no longer working after the user clicks a link to load a different gallery (there are five in total to choose from). It works on page refresh but once a seperate gallery is selected and the thumbs load it no longer works. Below is my jQuery code for the slideshow. I'm thinking that maybe I have missed a delegation somewhere or my functions are incorrectly organized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var timer = play()

function play() {
    i = setInterval(advanceImage, 4000);
    return i;
}

function pause() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}

var gallery = drawings;



//Creates array variable based on what user clicks
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $('#thumbs').children().remove();
    gallery = window[this.id];
    $.each(gallery, function(index, value){
        $('#thumbs').append('<img src="'+value+'" />');
    });
    return;
});

//Adding images to thumbs
$.each(gallery, function(index, value){
    $('#thumbs').append('<img src="'+value+'" />');
});

//Creates a current image from array
function currentImage(){
    i = jQuery.inArray($('#current-img').attr('src'), gallery);
    return i;
}

//Cycles through array
function advanceImage(){
    currentImage();
    if (i < gallery.length - 1){
        changeImage(i + 1);
    }else{
        changeImage(0)
    }
}

//Change current image to whatever i gives it
function changeImage(i){
    $('#current-img').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, 200, function(){
        $('#current-img').attr('src', gallery[i]);
        $('#slideshow-container img').load(function(){
            $('#current-img').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
            }, 200)
        })
    })
}

//Clicking thumbnail function
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    var newImage = $(this).attr('src');
    $.each(gallery, function(index, value){
        if (value == newImage){
            changeImage(index);
        };
    });
    clearInterval();
});



//Stop rotation on hover
$('#current-img').mouseenter(function() {
    pause();
})
$('#current-img').mouseleave(resetInterval);
    function resetInterval() {
        timer = play();
    }
```

Comment: post your html code and put it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your images after the DOM has already loaded. Therefore, your click function will not be attached to any of your images (which is why it isn't working). You need to attach your event handler to the document so it will handle images created after the DOM has loaded.

Change this:

```
//Clicking thumbnail function
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    var newImage = $(this).attr('src');
    $.each(gallery, function(index, value){
        if (value == newImage){
            changeImage(index);
        };
    });
    clearInterval();
});
```

to this:

```
//Clicking thumbnail function
$(document).on('click', '#thumbs img', function(){
    var newImage = $(this).attr('src');
    $.each(gallery, function(index, value){
        if (value == newImage){
            changeImage(index);
        };
    });
    clearInterval();
});
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/zuKRX/) - Notice that in this demo you can delete added images by clicking on them.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/zuKRX/1/) - Notice that in this demo, you cannot delete added images because of using `.click` instead of `.on`.